# Unable to visualize Inception v3 model in TensorBoard with TensorFlow 0.7.1

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm attempting to visualize Google's Inception v3 model using TensorBoard in TensorFlow 0.7.1 and am unable to do so. The TensorBoard Graph tab stalls with the statement

> Data : Reading graph.pbtxt

[image: Data : Reading graph.pbtxt]

I downloaded an un-Tarred the [inception v3 model](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/image/imagenet/inception-2015-12-05.tgz). The graph protobuffer is in `/tmp/imagenet/classify_image_graph_def.pb`.

Here's my code to dump the model:

```
import os
import os.path
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile

INCEPTION_LOG_DIR = '/tmp/inception_v3_log'

if not os.path.exists(INCEPTION_LOG_DIR):
    os.makedirs(INCEPTION_LOG_DIR)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    model_filename = '/tmp/imagenet/classify_image_graph_def.pb'
    with gfile.FastGFile(model_filename, 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
    writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(INCEPTION_LOG_DIR, graph_def)
    writer.close()
```

This dumps a 91 MB file called `events.out.tfevents.1456423256.[hostname]` (same size as the graph protobuffer) so it seems that the graph is in there somewhere.

I ran TensorBoard as follows:

```
tensorboard --logdir /tmp/inception_v3_log
```

Which results in the aforementioned hung loading bar on the Graph page.

The Chrome JavaScript console yields this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

which I assume is related to the fact that the graph is missing.

I've tried this with Chrome 48.0.2564.116 (64-bit) on OS X 10.11.3 both with TensorFlow 0.7.1 for Python 3 built using Bazel and TensorFlow 0.7.1 for Python 2 installed via pip with the exact same results.

I also verified that I *can* visualize the graph generated with the [mnist_with_summaries example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_with_summaries.py), so this is an issue specifically with the Inception model.

Comment: The official place to report TensorFlow bugs is on [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues)

Comment: Thank you @GuyCoder, I created an official issue: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1287

Answer (score 0):

Daniel,

I don't know about the protobuffer stuff you mention, but I think you may want to uninstall the protobuf and reinstall tensorflow.

After my upgrade (on Ubuntu) from  tensorflow v0.6 to v0.7.1 I found the following post when I had trouble launching the tensorboard.

I think there was a problem with protobuf. Talked about here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1134#issuecomment-185279000

I ended up uninstalling protobuf and reinstalling tensorboard. Now I can launch the board and view my graph. Good luck! :)

Don

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:
This works for me:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile
with tf.Session() as sess:
    model_filename ='YouGraphNameWithPath.pb'
    with gfile.FastGFile(model_filename, 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        g_in = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)
LOGDIR='PathWhereSummaryWillBeSaved'
train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(LOGDIR)
train_writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
```